# Thymeleaf configuration with springORM applcation

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-orm

I need to use thymeleaf instead of jsp in a  SpringORM application, I'm looking for the configuration setting for this purpose.

Comment: Google same thing you will get lots of results.

Answer (score 0):

create a simple spring boot project from https://start.spring.io/ and then add thymeleaf in your maven repository like below

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

N.B: You can also chhose thymeleaf as a dependency when you create the project.

Comment: its giving me error "Error resolving template [hello], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"

Comment: you have to keep hello.html in the templates folder

Comment: I have put it in templates folder, still it's giving the same error